# JPanel doesn't repaint Game of Life

Tags: java, swing

Basically *all* I wanted to do was when the `GUIoutput()` method in the Generation.java was invoked, it should repaint the Panel in GameOfLife.java.

However, with all the options I tried, like using `javax.swing.Timer` to replace `Thread.sleep`, none of them works. The `JPanel` will be the same as when it first started.

```
package life;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Universe();
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(GameOfLife::new);
    }
}
```

```
package life;

import static life.Universe.printUniverse;

public class Generation {
    private static int[][] universe = Universe.getUniverse();
    private static int size = Universe.getUniverse_size();
    private static int M;
    public Generation(){
        Universe.setUniverse(evolution());
        universe = Universe.getUniverse();
    }
    private void consoleOutput(){
        //clear console first
        /*
        try {
            if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows"))
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            else
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException ignored) {}*/
        //print out the statistics
        System.out.println("Generation #" + M);
        System.out.println("Alive: " + countAlive());
        printUniverse();
    }
    public static int countAlive(){
        int alive = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                if(universe[i][j] == 0){
                    alive++;
                }
            }
        }
        return alive;
    }

    private int[][] evolution(){
        int[][] newUniverse = new int[size][size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                int[] cell = new int[]{i, j};
                int neighboursAlive = cellDetector(cell);
                //System.out.println("for cell: "+ Arrays.toString(cell)+" "+ neighboursAlive); //test with 3 36 err here
                if(cellCondition(neighboursAlive, cell)){
                    newUniverse[i][j] = 0;//alive
                }else{
                    newUniverse[i][j] = 1;//dead
                }
            }
        }
        return newUniverse;
    }
    private boolean cellCondition(int neighboursAlive, int[] cell){
        int cellinUniverse = universe[cell[0]][cell[1]];
        if(cellinUniverse == 0 && (neighboursAlive == 2 || neighboursAlive == 3)){
            return true;
        }else if(cellinUniverse == 1 && neighboursAlive == 3){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //correct
    private int cellDetector(int[] cell){
        //if not border cell
        int i = cell[0];
        int j = cell[1];
        int neighboursAlive = 0;
        if(i < size - 1 && i > 0
                && j < size - 1 && j > 0){
            if(universe[i-1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//N
            if(universe[i-1][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NE
            if(universe[i+1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//S
            if(universe[i][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//E
            if(universe[i+1][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SE
            if(universe[i-1][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NW
            if(universe[i][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//W
            if(universe[i+1][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SW

        }else if(i == 0 && j > 0 && j < size - 1){
            //top row
            if(universe[i][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//W
            if(universe[i+1][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SW
            if(universe[i+1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//S
            if(universe[i+1][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SE
            if(universe[i][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//E

            if(universe[size-1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//N
            if(universe[size-1][j + 1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NE
            if(universe[size-1][j - 1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NW

        }else if(i == size - 1 && j > 0 && j < size - 1){
            //bottom row
            if(universe[i-1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//N
            if(universe[i-1][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NW
            if(universe[i-1][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NE
            if(universe[i][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//E
            if(universe[i][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//W

            if(universe[0][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//S
            if(universe[0][j + 1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SE
            if(universe[0][j - 1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SW

        }else if(i > 0 && i < size - 1 && j == 0){
            //first column
            if(universe[i+1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//S
            if(universe[i-1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//N
            if(universe[i+1][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SE
            if(universe[i-1][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NE
            if(universe[i][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//E

            if(universe[i+1][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SW
            if(universe[i][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//W
            if(universe[i-1][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NW

        }else if(i > 0 && i < size - 1 && j == size - 1){
            //last column
            if(universe[i+1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//S
            if(universe[i-1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//N
            if(universe[i-1][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NW
            if(universe[i+1][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SW
            if(universe[i][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//W

            if(universe[i+1][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SE
            if(universe[i][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//E
            if(universe[i-1][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NE

        }else if(i == 0 && j == 0){
            //up left corner
            if(universe[i+1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//S
            if(universe[i+1][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SE
            if(universe[i][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//E

            if(universe[size-1][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//N
            if(universe[size-1][1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NE
            if(universe[size-1][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NW
            if(universe[i][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//W
            if(universe[i+1][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SW

        }else if(i == 0 && j == size - 1){
            //up right corner
            if(universe[i][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//W
            if(universe[i+1][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SW
            if(universe[i+1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//S

            if(universe[0][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//E
            if(universe[1][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SE
            if(universe[size-1][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//N
            if(universe[size-1][size-2] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NW
            if(universe[size-1][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NE

        }else if(i == size - 1 && j == 0){
            //bottom left corner
            if(universe[i-1][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NE
            if(universe[i][j+1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//E
            if(universe[i-1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//N

            if(universe[0][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SW
            if(universe[0][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//S
            if(universe[0][1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SE
            if(universe[size-2][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NW
            if(universe[size-1][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//W

        }else if(i == size - 1 && j == size - 1){
            //bottom right corner
            if(universe[i-1][j] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//N
            if(universe[i-1][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NW
            if(universe[i][j-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//W

            if(universe[0][size-2] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SW
            if(universe[0][size-1] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//S
            if(universe[0][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//SE
            if(universe[size-2][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//NE
            if(universe[size-1][0] == 0) neighboursAlive++;//E
        }
        return neighboursAlive;
    }
}
```

```
package life;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static int size = Universe.getUniverse_size();
    private static int[][] universe = Universe.getUniverse();
    public GamePanel(){
        universe = Universe.getUniverse();
        setBounds(0, 40, 500, 500);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //500w && 500h
        int WIDTH = 500/size;
        int HEIGHT = 500/size;
        for ( int x = 0; x <= 500; x += WIDTH ) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 500; y += HEIGHT) {
                g.drawRect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                if(universe[i][j] == 0){
                    g.fillRect(i*WIDTH, j*HEIGHT, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
package life;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class GameOfLife extends JFrame {
    private static JLabel GLabel = new JLabel();
    private static JLabel ALabel = new JLabel();
    private static JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
    private static int M = 0;

    public GameOfLife() {
        setTitle("Game of Life");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(516, 579);
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        GenerationLabel();
        AliveLabel();
        GamePanel();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private void GamePanel(){
        Panel = new GamePanel();
        add(Panel);
        ActionListener refresh = e -> {
            new Generation();
            M++;
            GLabel.setText("Generation #" + M);
            ALabel.setText("Alive: " + Generation.countAlive());
            Panel.repaint();
            setVisible(true);
        };
        int UPDATE_SPEED = 700;
        new Timer(UPDATE_SPEED, refresh).start();
    }

    private void GenerationLabel(){
        GLabel.setName("GenerationLabel");
        GLabel.setText("Generation #0");
        GLabel.setBounds(5,0,100,20);
        add(GLabel);
    }
    private void AliveLabel(){
        ALabel.setName("AliveLabel");
        ALabel.setText("Alive: " + Generation.countAlive());
        ALabel.setBounds(5,20,100,20);
        add(ALabel);
    }

    public static JLabel getALabel() {
        return ALabel;
    }

    public static JLabel getGLabel() {
        return GLabel;
    }

    public static JPanel getPanel() {
        return Panel;
    }

    public static void setPanel(JPanel panel) {
        Panel = panel;
    }
}
```

```
package life;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Universe {
    private static int[][] universe;
    private static int universe_size = 20;
    private static long seed;
    private static int M;

    public Universe(){
        setup();
        populateUniverse();
    }

    private static void setup(){
        //System.out.println("Please input universe parameters:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        universe_size = 20; //scanner.nextInt();
        //seed = scanner.nextLong();
        //M = scanner.nextInt(); //num of gens
        universe = new int[universe_size][universe_size];
        for(int[] i: universe){
            Arrays.fill(i, 1);
        }
    }
    private static void populateUniverse(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < universe_size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < universe_size; j++) {
                if(rand.nextBoolean()){
                    universe[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void printUniverse(){
        for(int i = 0; i < universe_size; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < universe_size; j++){
                if(universe[i][j] == 0){
                    System.out.print("O");//alive
                }else if(universe[i][j] == 1){
                    System.out.print(" ");//dead
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[][] getUniverse() {
        return universe;
    }

    //public static int getM() {
    //    return M;
    //}

    public static int getUniverse_size() {
        return universe_size;
    }

    public static void setUniverse(int[][] universe) {
        Universe.universe = universe;
    }
}
```

I have tried to remove thread and added a timer, but JPanel refused to update.

Comment: *"already tired many options on Stackoverflow" - so no one mentioned that Swing is single thread AND not thread safe and that long running or blocking operations, like a `while (true)` executed on the event dispatching thread would cause the UI to "freeze" and become non-responsive?  And no one mentioned maybe using a `SwingWorker` or, if you were careful, a `Thread` to offload the "long running operations" from the Event Dispatching Thread?

Comment: Should also discuss that fact that `static` is not a means for cross object communication and is usually a sign of a bad design - also, you're missing `Universe`, so it's going to be impossible for any one to really know exactly what's wrong

Comment: I would, however, suggest taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and possibly even [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a slightly different approach

Comment: Added Universe.java

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just started programming a month ago....

Comment: You've already got your help. Please see the last comment of @MadProgrammer. It's all you need. Please rewrite your code without `Thread.sleep(xxx)` invocations. Move your code from loop of `Generation` constructor into a `javax.swing.Timer` invokation. Invokation of `repaint()` provides no direct repaint. It simply put a repaint task on the top of the EventQueue. Execution of repaint goes started when all your code is done.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I added javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(GameOfLife::new); on Main and moved the loop into GamePanel() under GameOfLife.java but it still doesn't work; I used actionlistener for the loop and executed it using the Timer

Answer (score 0):

Wow, the answer is actually the *Universe* variable isn't handled properly, causing JPanel to not update. LOL.

Comment: Yes, you have to love `static`